# What's the difference between "const Node& n" and "Node &n"?

Tags: c++

What's the difference between `const Node& n` and `Node &n`?

Following is my understanding:

1. For `Node &n` I guess once it is initialized it can't be changed.
2. For `const Node& n` it cannot change the content of Node passed.

Is this right? Or, can somebody explain?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is correct.

`Node &n` means you cannot assign a "different node" to that reference (make `n` reference a different `Node`) but you can change the contents of the referenced `Node`.

`const Node &n` prohibits any updates to the referenced `Node` (in addition to the restrictions described above for the non-const)